# How to send sound input from HTML to server

Tags: javascript, jquery, audiocontext, webkitaudiocontext

I need to send sound input to server. Can I send it as variable? What should I do in the function `start_microphone()`, and what methods of `AudioContext()` should I use?

```
var input = null;
var webaudio_tooling_obj = function() {
    var audioContext = new AudioContext();
    console.log("audio is starting up ...");
    var BUFF_SIZE = 16384;
    var audioInput = null,

    if (!navigator.getUserMedia)
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
            navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({
            audio: true
        }, function(stream) {
            start_microphone(stream);
        }, function(e) {
            alert('Error capturing audio.');
        });
    } else {
        alert('getUserMedia not supported in this browser.');
    }

    function start_microphone(stream) {
        ///////////////////
    }
}();

function sendInput() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click(function() {
            $.post("/tuner/getfreq/", {
                "sound": input
            }, function(data, status) {
                document.getElementById("post").innerHTML = data;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: To send a file to the server you need to upload it. I would suggest using AJAX for this. If you Google 'AJAX file upload' there are already a lot of questions covering this topic

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan If you look at the code, you see that the upload part isn't the problem here.

Comment: @ThanawatKahothong Rather than using a server-side tuner, why not just do it client-side?  This is a well covered example use case of the Web Audio API.

Comment: @Brad I know - that's why I only left that comment, to help with the uploading part

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Before that,i don't know what to do in function. thank you for your advice.It would be useful to me.

Comment: https://subvisual.co/blog/posts/39-tutorial-html-audio-capture-streaming-to-node-js-no-browser-extensions - might be a helpful start.

Comment: @ThanawatKahothong You can either use MediaRecorder to create a full media file with headers and all that, or just send raw PCM samples (use a ScriptProcessorNode).

Comment: @axel.michel thank you :)

Comment: @Brad  ScriptProcessNode can send sound as a variable? i don' t know how use it, thank you for your advice.